# PHP - execute Sql Server stored procedure with 2 output parameters

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with a third-party company in order to integrate an web application with their Windows application.

To write the necessary data into their database they gave me the following procedure:

```
Declare @SavedOK int, @Message varchar(8000)
Exec pbProcessTransactions
  @SavedOK output,
  @Message output
```

I have to execute it with PHP, this is how I've written my application, and for this I used something that I've found on Micrsoft's documentations.

My code which executes the stored procedure with 2 output parameters is:

```
$tsql_callSP = "{call pbProcessTransactions(?, ? )}";

$SavedOK = '';
settype($SavedOK, "integer");
$Message = '';
settype($Message, "string");
$raspuns = '';

$params = array(
array($SavedOK, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
array($Message, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
);

/* Execute the query. */
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);

if( $stmt3 === false ) {
echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }

/* Display the value of the output parameters. */
while ($obj=sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt3)) {
// SET PARAMETERS - SET TERMS
echo $obj->SavedOK;
echo $obj->Message;
}
/*Free the statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);

/*WHERE SavedOK and Message are the 2 output parameters which will display     various info depending if the procedure executes normally or not, SavedOK will display 1 or 0 , 1 if it's ok 0 if not and Message will display the error message if SavedOK is 0 */
```

My problem is that the statement is always false, it always displays **"Error in executing statement 3"** and I cannot see the output, if SavedOK is 1 or 0, which is the message.

Comment: just askin : Since $SavedOK is supposed to store/return only integer, did you try initializaing it as  $SavedOK = 0   instead of $SavedOk = '' . It would anyway default to 0 when you apply settype on '' .

Comment: Do you see other similar code running well ? Are you sure you met the requirements mentioned here before you can use sqlserv_query ?
http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php

Comment: I use other procedures in my application wich work. But they are different and i use EXEC to call them not CALL like here.For example i have a procedure wich brings me data acording to some parameters and it's working perferct withou error.I dont have a problem with sqlserv driver it's working. I dont know it is something that looks wrong in my code ?

Comment: Did you try something like  
print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)
 to check the nature of errors you are getting ? 
Such as in the examples here : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php